# PyQt QRadioButton toggled singal callback execute after delete

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I faced a very wired problem when i use QRadioButton, the simple code as below:

```
class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__()
        self._init_ui()

    def _init_ui(self):
        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def refresh_radio_btn(self):
        pyqt_util.clear_layout(self.layout())

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.radio_btn = QRadioButton("test_btn")
        self.radio_btn.setChecked(True)
        self.radio_btn.toggled.connect(self._on_toggled)
        layout.addWidget(self.radio_btn)

        self.layout().addLayout(layout)

    def _on_toggled(self):
        print('_on_toggledsaaa')
        import traceback
        traceback.print_stack()
```

If i call `refresh_radio_btn` twice, the func `_on_toggled` will execute, for the code `self.radio_btn.setChecked(True)`.But if i add a delay 0s between two execution using QTimer, or add `self.radio_btn.disconnet` before `self.radio_btn = QRadioButton("test_btn")`, `_on_toggled` will not execute. And when `_on_toggled` executed, the sender will beocome a `QObject` rather `QRadioButton`.

The code i give will not occur this problem, it is a simple version of my original code.

Comment: Probably because you use `deleteLater()` when clearing the layout, which won't delete anything until control returns to the event-loop. Using a timer will itself post an event, which allows processing of any pending deletion events.

Comment: @ekhumoro i knew it is related to `deleteLater() `, but did not know the detail why this happen. it is so wired, one obj fired a singal, another object catch it and trigger the callback